# TypeError: props.onLoggedIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, axios, react-props

I have a main view where users login/register to see movies and the login view page has a function that when you submit, is supposed to query the function in main view.

##### Main View:

```
export class MainView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Initial state is set to null
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      user: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (accessToken !== null) {
      this.setState({
        user: localStorage.getItem("user"),
      });
      this.getMovies(accessToken);
    }
  }

  /* When a user successfully logs in, this function updates the `user` property in state to that *particular user*/
  onLoggedIn(authData) {
    console.log(authData);
    this.setState({
      user: authData.user.Username,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("token", authData.token);
    localStorage.setItem("user", authData.user.Username);
    this.getMovies(authData.token);
  }

  onLoggedOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    this.setState({
      user: null,
    });
  }

  getMovies(token) {
    axios
      .get(`https://app.herokuapp.com/movies`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // Assign the result to the state
        this.setState({
          movies: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

##### Login View:

```
export function LoginView(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // Declare hook for each input
  const [usernameErr, setUsernameErr] = useState("");
  const [passwordErr, setPasswordErr] = useState("");

  // validate user inputs
  const validate = () => {
    let isReq = true;

    if (!username) {
      setUsernameErr("Username required");
      isReq = false;
    } else if (username.length < 2) {
      setUsernameErr("Username must be at least 2 characters long");
      isReq = false;
    }
    if (!password) {
      setPasswordErr("Password required");
      isReq = false;
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
      setPassword("Password must be at least 6 characters long");
      isReq = false;
    }

    return isReq;
  };
  

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isReq = validate();
    if (isReq) {
      /* Send request to the server for authentication */
      axios
        .post(`https://app.herokuapp.com/login`, {
          Username: username,
          Password: password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
         props.onLoggedIn(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, "no such user");
        });
    }
  };
```

For some reason it tells me that `props.onLoggedIn` is not a function, which I have already imported in to `MainView` (I mean `LoginView`) which should recognise the function. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: would you write the rendering part of your components?

Comment: where and how you pass the props the your `LoginView` component?

Comment: How are you passing the function of `loggedIn` from `Main view` to `Login view`? In order for `Login` to utilize the function you must pass the function as a `prop` from `Main` to `Login`. 

Should look something like:

`function MainView() {
return (
<LoginView onLoggedIn = {this.LoggedIn}/>
)
}`

Comment: I imported the LoginView File to MainView, like: `import {LoginView} from "../LoginView/login-view.jsx.`

Comment: @pythonNovice That's what I understand when it comes to separating pages but using both code.